# How can i use Comparator to implement Bubble sort?

Tags: java, bubble-sort

How can i implement Bubble sort by using Comparator?

Thank you.

This is how my comparator looks:

```
class ColumnSorter implements Comparator {
  int colIndex;

  ColumnSorter(int colIndex) {
    this.colIndex = colIndex;
  }

  public int compare(Object a, Object b) {
  Vector v1 = (Vector) a;
  Vector v2 = (Vector) b;
  Object o1 = v1.get(colIndex);
  Object o2 = v2.get(colIndex);

  if (o1 instanceof String && ((String) o1).length() == 0) {
    o1 = null;
  }
  if (o2 instanceof String && ((String) o2).length() == 0) {
    o2 = null;
  }

  if (o1 == null && o2 == null) {
    return 0;
  } else if (o1 == null) {
    return 1;
  } else if (o2 == null) {
    return -1;
  } else if (o1 instanceof Comparable) {
      return ((Comparable) o1).compareTo(o2);
  } else {
    return o1.toString().compareTo(o2.toString());
 }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You implement bubble sort just as you would with, say `<`. Then you replace the use of `<` with `someComparator.compare(Object o1, Object o2)`.

Here's the "translation rule":

```
if (arr[i] < arr[j]) {
    ...
}
```

becomes

```
if (someComparator.compare(arr[i], arr[j]) < 0) {
    ...
}
```

(If you used `>`, you would use `> 0` instead of `< 0`.)

You should consult [the documentation for `Comparator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for further details. Here's the first sentence:

> Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

Comment: ohhh okay, so there is no special way of implement bubble sort right? Just implment bubble sort normally right?

Comment: Yes. I would assume so. The comparator is only good for comparing elements. It won't perform any swaps or sorting of any kind.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you know how to code a Bubble Sort and that the problem is how to use a Comparator.

At every iteration in the bubble sort you have to compare two items to decide which order they should be in. Where you would say:

`if item1 < item2 then`

you now write:

`if( comparator.compare(item1,item2) < 0 ) {`

If you would say:

`if item1 > item2 then`

then you write

`if( comparator.compare(item1,item2) > 0 ) {`

Note that the `<` and `>` remain the same and you keep the order of the items the same. If you stick to that rule the comparison should work fine, so all that is left is the actual bubble sort.

Comment: I have a custom comparator, so how would i do it then?

Comment: Your comparator should be an instance of the java.util.Comparator class. You simply use that instance as I indicated above.

Comment: yes, you are correct but i have to sort columns in a JTable, so i have to make a custom comparator to compare the items in column.

Comment: And? I can't do your homework for you :-) What kind of things are in this JTable? Could it be text and numbers by any chance? These classes all implement the `Comparable` interface, which is closely related to `Comparator`. If you had a Comparator for Comparable objects, you might save yourself some work :-)

Comment: What do you exactly mean why "If you had a Comparator for Comparable objects" I don't get it? Can you please explain? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The big question is why on earth you would want to implement a bubble sort by yourself. Bubble sort is one of the slowest sorting algorithms around.

Using the sorting algorithm provided by the JDK in [`java.util.Collections.sort()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) would be much faster *and* save you quite some lines of code. `Collections.sort()` has a method that takes a `Comparator`, or one without that uses the natural ordering of objects (if they implement the `Comparable` interface).